# How to subclass UINavigationBar correctly also using appearance

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

This is **what I am trying to achieve:**
[image: NavigationBar]
NB: Also with a title to the controller.

Some additional information:-

1. This navigation bar will appear on around 10 view controllers.
2. It is not part of a Navigation Controller, as not required to be.
3. The button on the left is static (will always be on the navigation bar).
4. The right button is not static and will either not exist or be
   different on the different View Controllers.
5. The left button acts as a sliding menu (i.e. menu slides in underneath from left)
6. I am using storyboard in the setup

**Question**
What is the correct way to achieve this?

**Existing Code**
I have tried to implement this, but I can only get one or the other of the buttons, without a title working. To implement the background I used the appearance API as below:

**didFinishLaunching...**

```
// Custom Navigation Bar appearance setup
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                       [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                       [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],
                                                       UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,nil]];
// Used to deal with the rotation of the nav bar when implemented outside of Navigation Controller
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

// Set the background image
UIImage *imageBg = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"mainNavBar"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,5,0,5)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:imageBg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// Used to push the title down slightly when in Landscape and NavBar outside of Navigation Controller
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:2 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

I then subclassed UINavigationBar for the left button creation with the following:
**Subclass of UINavigationBar: awakeFromNib**

```
UINavigationItem* ni = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
UIButton *leftButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 38.0f, 29.0f)];
[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuBarItem"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(menuItemPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[leftButton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[leftButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
UIBarButtonItem *b =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
ni.leftBarButtonItem = b;
self.items = @[ni];
```

Then within the storyboard I add a NavigationBar to the VC in question and link to the correct subclass. I also add an additional button item to the navigation bar in the storyboard for that controller and link to an outlet. Then within the VC I try to update the title and right button with the below:

**View Controller that holds the subclassed Nav Bar: viewDidLoad**

```
// Set VC Title for NavBar
self.title  = NSLocalizedString(@"NavBarHomeTitle", @"Navigation Bar - Home page title");

// Setup the right navigation bar item
UIImage *addImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"addGameButton"];
UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, addImage.size.width, addImage.size.height)];
[addButton setBackgroundImage:addImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addGameButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.rightBarButtonItem setCustomView:addButton];
```

The result is a navigation bar with only the left button. Now I believe this is due to the awakeFromNib code above alloc init a new UINavigationItem therefore I cannot control the title and add a button to it. How can I complete this? Is this the best approach or are there others I cannot see any in-depth tutorials on how to approach this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your better option is to use a navigation controller, it acts as the controller that interrogates the view controller it's currently displaying and updates the navigation bar.

Rather than subclass the navigation bar, you should subclass the navigation controller. Then whenever the displayed view controller changes you can set the left button item by adding it to the navigation item of that view controller. Each view controller can specify whatever right bar button item(s) it requires.

The simplest way to do this is for the navigation controller to act as its own delegate and implement `navigationController:willShowViewController:`. Using this method it can access the `navigationItem` of the passed view controller and set the `leftBarButtonItem`. You also have access to the other methods of the navigation and view controllers if required.

Each view controller would also, in `viewDidLoad`, set its `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem(s)` to appropriate buttons for the requirements of its view. Such as your 'addGameButton' bar button.

Working this way, the appearance will work as you have it, the title of the view controller will work automatically and you have full control, and a number if methods in your navigation controller subclass, to perform your button and interaction customisations.

Comment: thanks, could you provide a little more information on how to accomplish this please? I understand the subclassing the navigation controller but I am unsure on how to set the items along with '..can specify whatever right bar button item(s) it requires'... for each VC?

Comment: I think the problem with this route is that I have around 10 view controllers which would need to be in their own Navigation Controllers? OR do you mean to have the one navigation controller and push a new root view controller each time?

Comment: How are you 10 view controllers related to each other?

Comment: I use a sliding menu ECSlidingViewController. So there is a controller that slides in underneath on the left, select a different option from the table view and the new controller is pushed to the main view. This is pushed to the self.slidingviewcontroller.topviewcontroller property, which deallocs the old and pushses the new

Comment: In that case, each time a new selection is made you'd create an instance of your navigation controller, set the instance of your view controller as its root and set the nav controller as the sliding top view controller. Truly none of your view controllers have a second (or detail) view?

Comment: No, a couple start a new navigation controller instance and return back to this main view. Is this the best way to approach this, can this not be achieved with the navigation bar subclass? I am finding when I create a new instance of the navigation controller subclass the old is not dealloc'd.

Comment: It could be done with a custom navigation bar subclass, but the navigation controller method is (should be) easier and a better design (because it encapsulates the button logic in a controller class, not a view class). Do you mean to say that you now have a leak? Verified by Instruments?

Comment: Ok, I have sorted the leak now, progress :) Now I need to know how I should build the buttons in this new UINavigationController subclass. How do I add buttons to the navigation bar based on the View Controller or should I add the buttons in the storyboard for each VC?

Comment: I downloaded this - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html - But I would like to confirm... from this I gather I should add the buttons to the navigation bars for each VC in the storyboard that has this navigation controller. However, in my storyboard only one view controller is linked to navigation controller (via root controller) which means the navigation bar only shows on one. I guess I can still implement in code, but is this the correct route?

Comment: Whenever a view controller is pushed into a navigation controller and becomes visible (as root or not) its navigation item bar buttons will be shown by the navigation controller. For any view controller is Xcode you can show the navigation bar using the utilities inspector.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29834/discussion-between-stuartm-and-wain)

Comment: NB: Cannot award bounty directly but it will be awarded to marked answer

Comment: @Wain "view controller would also, in viewDidLoad, set its self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem(s)" - why does each subview have to implement this? As opposed to just calling it in the parent class? Cheers