# UINavigationController subclass not calling willShowViewController when expected

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationitem, uinavigationcontroller

I have implemented an application with a slide in styled menu using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController)

At present I have the following setup:
An initial View Controller subclass of ECSlidingViewController. This handles the pushing of top view controller (the main view displayed on screen) and the underLeftController which is the menu.

The menu is a tableview controller subclass when a row is clicked a new top view controller is pushed onto the stack.

Per a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373345/how-to-subclass-uinavigationbar-correctly-also-using-appearance) I use a Navigation Controller (subclassed) which holds a single root view controller. Each time a row is selected a new instance of the navigation controller is loaded with a different view controller, the old dealloc'd. For example:

```
// Check if the settings view is currently displayed if it is just reset the top view else load it to the topviewcontroller.
                UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.slidingViewController.topViewController;
                UIViewController *VC = navController.topViewController;
                if ([VC isKindOfClass:[MESSettingsViewController class]]) {
                    [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
                } else {
                    MESMainNavViewController *mainNavController = [[MESMainNavViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsVC"]];

                    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

                    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
                        CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
                        self.slidingViewController.topViewController = mainNavController;
                        self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
                        [weakSelf.slidingViewController resetTopViewWithAnimations:nil onComplete:^{
                            [weakSelf updateCurrentCell];
                        }];
                    }];
                }
```

This is all working fine at the moment. The issue I have is with a login sequence. If a user logs out a different navigation stack is pushed on modally. Once the user completes a successful login a notification is made. This is received by the Initial View Controller (from above):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didLoginUser) name:@"LoginCompleteNotification" object:nil];
```

The method then handles pushing the user to a new instance of the subclassed navigation controller in question, with the home controller as the root.

```
// If the view controller is not home send them to home
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.topViewController;
UIViewController *VC = navController.topViewController;
if (![VC isKindOfClass:[MESHomeViewController class]]) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }

    MESMainNavViewController *mainNavController = [[MESMainNavViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"]];

    self.topViewController = mainNavController;
    [self resetTopView];

}
```

The problem appears to be with the following part:

```
MESMainNavViewController *mainNavController = [[MESMainNavViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"]];

self.topViewController = mainNavController;
```

When this new instance of the navigation controller is created the delegate method `willShowViewController` does not appear to be called? I cannot find out why, it calls it when the controller is changed via the menu table view and it uses the same method to create, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The apple docs states that

> The UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol defines methods a
>   navigation controller delegate can implement to change the behavior
>   when view controllers are pushed and popped from the stack of a
>   navigation controller.

So, I think the method `willShowViewController` will be called only if you push or pop a view controller to/from the navigation stack.

Comment: I agree, but as a new instance of the navigation controller is being created it is pushing a controller. When the menu system works per the code in the question, each time a new instance is created and the push method is called. It just doesnt appear to be called in the second part?

Comment: Yep, I double checked and it seems that `initWithRoot` pushes the view controller on the stack, but I'm not sure that this push will call the  delegates methods. Another thing that cross to my mind, where do you set the nav controller delegate ?

Comment: the uinavigationcontroller is its own delegate, it is currently set in the viewDidLoad of MESMainNavViewController